# Why do I get a ContentLoadException in Monogame?

Tags: c#, monogame

I try to load a picture named kodo.jpg.
I made a copy of this picture in the Content folder.

```
public Texture2D kodo;
Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
kodo = Content.Load<Texture2D>("kodo");
```

In the last line I get the error ContentLoadException. But why?

Comment: Did you set the image to copy to the build directory?

Comment: Rather than embedding the solution into the answer post it below as an _answer_.  Then you can accept it.  Considering your points you should have been aware of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the picture-file, go to quick properties and set: Copy to output directory.